# Trying to bake sound with a context override through Python

Tags: python, audio, graph-editor

I'm working on an audio visualizer mostly from scratch. I'm trying to override the context so I can run `bpy.ops.graph.sound_bake()` but for some reason I can't get the context right. The code is below, as well as the stack trace. What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```
for window in bpy.context.window_manager.windows:
    screen = window.screen
    for area in screen.areas:
        if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
            area_type = area.type
            area_ui_type = area.ui_type
            area.type = 'GRAPH_EDITOR'
            area.ui_type = 'FCURVES'
            with bpy.context.temp_override(window=window, area=area):
                bpy.ops.graph.sound_bake(filepath=file)
            area.type = area_type
            area.ui_type = area_ui_type
```

Stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                                               File "E:\Git\music\blender.py", line 348, in <module>
main(music_file)
File "E:\Git\music\blender.py", line 336, in main
create_centerpiece(file, 16)
File "E:\Git\music\blender.py", line 319, in create_centerpiece
bpy.ops.graph.sound_bake(filepath=file)
File "C:\Users\devin gardner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\bpy\3.6\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 113, in __call__
ret = _op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.graph.sound_bake.poll() failed, context is incorrect
```

Added sample `.blend` file:

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6101/poll-failed-context-incorrect-example-bpy-ops-view3d-background-image-add

Comment: I appreciate the attempt, but this link hasn't helped me so far. It's one of the few I keep revisiting and I've correctly change the area's type and ui_type to no avail.

Comment: can you share your blend file? or a simple setup that reproduces the problem https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: Added it in an edit. This is what I'm able to generate in Python so far.

Comment: what is the file in `bpy.ops.graph.sound_bake(filepath=file)` it's not defined in your code.

Comment: the file variable just points to a local mp3 file. it's a full filepath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I could not find any animations or fcurves in your blend file, I added a random animation for 1 object so I could generate an fcurve just for demonstration purposes. Then you have to select an fcurve in the *Graph Editor* before you execute the script.

[image]

So basically you were not in the right context because nothing was selected. That is evident in that you can see that the command for `bpy.ops.graph.sound_bake` is grayed out in the menu until you select an fcurve.

[image]

Comment: I see. In that case, I'll need to figure out how to programmatically generate an fcurve and then select it before I try to bake the sound. I'm doing all of this from a Python script, instead of inside Blender.

Comment: @DevinGardner Yes it's easy to select an fcurve via python. Like for example (assuming the 'Plane' object had animation data), you can use `bpy.data.objects['Plane'].animation_data.action.fcurves[0].select = True`. Put that line before you execute the script then it will also work. So no need to manually select an fcurve. You just have to make sure you select the right fcurve.